# System.NotSupportedException When trying to serialize class to xml

Tags: c#, xml, zip, telerik

I'm trying to implement the `IXmlSerialization` for class `SerializableDictionary`. When starts the serialization of class to xml, I'm catching the `System.NotSupportedException: 'Can't flush final block twice'`. The problem occurs when second serializer trying to call `Serialize` method on same `XmlWriter`.

### Exception

```
System.NotSupportedException
  HResult=0x80131515
  Message=Can't flush final block twice
  Source=Telerik.Windows.Zip
  StackTrace:
   at Telerik.Windows.Zip.OperationStream.FlushFinalBlock()
   at System.Xml.XmlUtf8RawTextWriter.Flush()
   at System.Xml.XmlWellFormedWriter.Flush()
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle, String id)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o)
   at MP.SharedToolbox.XmlInOut.SerializableDictionary`2.WriteXml(XmlWriter writer) in C:\Users\britikov\Documents\Projects\SharedToolbox\XmlInOut\SerializableDictionary.cs:line 69
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterRegulationItem.Write19_LoadCard(String n, String ns, LoadCard o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterRegulationItem.Write20_RegulationItem(String n, String ns, RegulationItem o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterRegulationItem.Write21_Regulation(Object o)
```

*There is no info about InnerException.*

**UPD_0**: I found a problem. Problem occurs when I'm trying to serialize the class into a Stream of Entry inside archive. I'm using Telerik.Windows.Zip for creating archives and creating a entries for them. I fixed it with additional `MemoryStream` into which I will serialize the object and I will copy it into entry stream than. But I do not understand why with the stream of entry it occurs a problem and with `MemoryStream` it is not.

**UPD_1** I uploaded all source code to [github](https://github.com/mpcapchka/Example_1d1bbccf.git)

**Is there some way how to implement it correctly?**

Comment: Try following : valueSerializer.Serialize(writer, this[key].Value);

Comment: I can't reproduce it. Which specific type is used as `TValue`?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov there were used a `string` for `TValue` and `byte` for `Tkey`

Comment: 1) What is the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the exception type, message, traceback, and inner exception(s) if any?  2) Can you share a [mcve] including the code for `XmlInOut<RegulationItem>.SaveToStream(entry.Open(), item)`?  It looks like maybe you're closing or disposing of the zip stream more than once, which is is causing the problem (even though it should not).

Comment: @dbc I added more info about exception, and created a repo with the code on github. If you will launch this Console Application you will get this exception. Also for executing code you will need to get this library [download a trial version] (https://www.telerik.com/download)

Comment: Just a hunch, but it could be a bug in the disposal pattern of the library. Because stream buffers get flushed when they are disposed. And if for some reason dispose gets called twice, or the buffer already was flushed, this could lead to an error if this was not properly registered. But, like said, this is just a hunch.